# How to open Password Protected PDF/DOC in UIWebview without using a temp file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, cgpdf

We are trying to open a password protected PDF/DOC file in UIWebview. Due to security concern, we can only retrieve the files from server and store into memory (i.e. NSData), but cannot store as a file.

We tried to use loaddata function in UIWebiew and it can only success to load doc/xls/ppt/pdf without password protected.

For doc/xls files with password, it shows "Unable to Read Document. The operation couldn't be completed (QuickLookErrorDomain error 44820/912". May I ask how can we open the file in UIWebview?

For pdf file with password, it shows "The document "blank" is password protected". May I ask how can we show the correct document name instead of "Blank"?

I have also searched the cgpdf and know how to unlock the pdf file as CGPDFDocumentRef, but cannot find the way to change it back to NSData and input into UIWebview directly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write file in local and read the data and show it in web view

```
//convert file data(ie : NSData) as string
NSData *fileData;//This is the data from your request
NSString *fileString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//get the file path
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.pdf"];

//Save as file
NSError *error;
BOOL hasFileWritten = [fileString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if(!hasFileWritten)
{
    NSLog(@"Write file error: %@", error);
}

//open pdf in webview
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

**Update**
without writing the file data in local, Process the data in memory and show the pdf file in webview

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
    CATiledLayer *tiledLayer;
    CGPDFPageRef pageRef;
}
@end


CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url);

BOOL success = CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(pdf, "test");

if(success)
{
    pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, 1);

    CGRect pageRect = self.view.frame;

    tiledLayer = [CATiledLayer layer];
    tiledLayer.delegate = self;
    tiledLayer.tileSize = CGSizeMake(1024.0, 1024.0);
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetail = 1000;
    tiledLayer.levelsOfDetailBias = 1000;
    tiledLayer.frame = pageRect;

    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:pageRect];
    [contentView.layer addSublayer:tiledLayer];

    [webView addSubview:contentView];
}


- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(ctx));
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, layer.bounds.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(pageRef, kCGPDFCropBox, layer.bounds, 0, true));
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, pageRef);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. However one of the requirement for this task is we cannot save anything on the device, thus we cannot save it as a file. write file cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can show the password protected pdf now. However after I open the pdf, click the home button and back to my app, the app crashes. Is that I need to remove the subview correctly in viewWillDisappear?

Comment: On the other hand, any ideas on doc/xls files?

Comment: @Forrest for crashing issue, you have to remove the tiledLayer from its super layer and make delegate to nil on viewWillDisappear.                 tiledLayer.delegate = nil;
    [tiledLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

Comment: doc/slx and other MS office files can be opened using Web view. I get webView:didFailLoadWithError:][599] Error loading file Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The URL can’t be shown" error for MS office files

Answer (score 0):

in order to unlock an protected PDF file, you have to use [CGPDFDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/)

then using [CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFDocument/#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword) you can unlock your file, UIWebView is much simpler, but your case requires `CGPDFDocument`

here is a [library](https://github.com/vfr/Reader) which could be useful for you

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I mentioned in my question, I know how to unlock the pdf by CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword and get the unlocked pdf in CGPDFDocumentRef. However I am not able to find the way to change it back to NSData or show it in UIWebview without saving as a file.